# JDBC / IntelliJ Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a small test program in IntelliJ. Code:

```
String driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://test.test.com;integratedSecurity=true";
    String userName = "test";
    String password = "test";
    Class.forName(driverClass);
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
         Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
         Statement st2 = con.createStatement();
    ) {
      String sql1 = "EXEC  [dbo].[Cleanup]";
      String sql2 = "EXEC  [dbo].[DetailsALL] \"DetailsALL.csv\" ";
      st1.execute(sql1);
      st2.execute(sql2);

    }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I have added following to the VM options:

-Djava.library.path="\Users\sgupta\IdeaProjects\todos\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86\"
[image]

Running the program results in:

**Apr 05, 2013 5:43:20 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI 
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:db8a3aa3-d84b-49d2-a7eb-64c4187a8303**

i have double checked the path I have specified in the VM option. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What OS do you use? Are you sure this library is compatible with it? The paths tell me that you are on Mac, but the library is trying to load the `.dll`. Using backslashes in paths on Mac is also wrong.

Comment: Remove the quotes around the path

Comment: I did use forward slashes first, when that didn't work tried the backslashes. Yes I am on Mac.

Comment: Tried again with forward slashes, same result. Removed quotes, same result.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like I have some bad news for you.  This is straight from the sqljdbc documentation that is included with the .tar.gz file.  After you upack the file, go to this help webpage: sqljdbc_4.0/enu/help/default.htm

Under Contents >>> Connecting to SQL Server with the JDBC Driver >>> Building the Connection URL, go to the section: "Connecting with Integrated Authentication"

At the bottom of this section is has the following quote, which basically says you can't use the dll approach for non-windows systems.

> The JDBC driver does not support the integrated authentication when the driver runs on non-Windows operating systems. The driver also does not provide any functionality to supply Windows Authentication credentials, such as user name and password, when connecting to SQL Server from non-Windows operating systems. In such cases, the applications must use SQL Server Authentication instead.

However, this same help file's equivalent msdn documentation seems to suggest that for all non-windows operating systems, you can get it to work with Kerberos.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx

This msdn link gives an overview of the the Kerberos process, but it falls short on a detailed setup for non-windows machines.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122.aspx

If anyone has figured out the details for getting Kerberos working to connect to SQL Server from a non-windows machine, I'd love to hear from them.

Comment: You can look here for a detailed explanation on how to use Kerberos to connect to SQL Server from a non-Windows platform: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication.aspx